# How to simulate touch events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch, kinect

I am working on a touch application using Kinect's depth sensor.
I am able to get the points where the user puts it's fingers, but I'd like to fire the corresponding Touch events.

For example, i'd like to be able to send `TouchDown`, `Touch Up`, `Touch Move` events.

I took a look at `TouchDevice` and `TouchPoint` classes, but I don't see how I should do this. I tried to create a fake `TouchPoint` and added it to a custom `TouchDevice`, but I don't know what to do next.

I tried to do a `ReportDown` but it only fires `Touch_FrameReported` with empty arguments.

So my question is, how do one fires the touch system events ? Is it possible with these classes, or should I go with windows messages (`WM_TOUCH` and `WM_GESTURE`) ?

Comment: Where are you trying to raise the event and on what object(s) are you trying to raise them on?  Have you looked into calling `RaiseEvent` to fire touch events from your Kinect callbacks?

Comment: In fact, we are developing a custom Kinect library (because we are only trying to recognize the hands of the user, on a table). In this library, we are able to raise our custom events like 'fingerDown' and get the coordinates. These events should be raised in a Window, on multiple types of controls (images, userControls, buttons, sliders).
The idea is to make that library able to raise the corresponding system touch events so the applications using our library won't care about this part of the code

Comment: Is `RaiseEvent` really the way to go ? If I'm right, it needs to have a reference of the target object, therefore I should first get it by code, with the position of the touch. But a library should not have to do this.

Comment: Not sure if it the ultimate way to go, which is why I made a comment and not an answer.  Fishing for information and trying to get a better picture so I can think of what might be the best approach.  Really, you shouldn't be simulating touch at all - your UI should be coded to accept native events from the input scheme you are using (e.g., gestures), and the look-and-feel should be designed around that input scheme.  But if you are wanting to simulate, `RaiseEvent` may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure about what your are meaning by "native events from the input scheme you are using". Do you suggest that our UI should be able to understand our library's events (like `Fingerdown` and such)? I think it would be way harder, since we would have to handle ourselves manipulations. Or do you mean that we should raise existing system events like `ManipulationStarted`, `OnTouchDown` with `RaiseEvent`?

Comment: I mean the first - you should support custom events.  I suggest looking at the "Basic Interactions" example in the Microsoft Kinect Toolkit, that comes with the SDK.  It may take more time up front, but will benefit you 10x in the future... in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know if this could be useful for you. The new Kinect SDK 1.7 have Kinect Interactions. That can simulate pushing a button.

Comment: I finally raised WPF events (`TouchDown`, `TouchUp`...) with `RaiseEvent` by getting the controls from `InputHitTest`.
I'm still not sure it is the best way to go, but it did the work.
Thanks for you help Evil Closet Monkey !
(I will look to Interactions from SDK 1.7 later)